# gallery displaying multiple rows after refresh for a few millisecs but should display only one row

Tags: html, css

i have this bug on my site, dont know what could I do to change it so it will be displayed correctly.

My problem is the filmstrip on my site [kecy.sk](http://www.kecy.sk) a.k.a gallery... when I refresh, there are elements appearing and then dissapearing and work properly... But that first look is ugly... It is supose to be displayed in one row as it is. but when I do refresh the page, I see those pictures in filmstrip stack for a little while in multiple rows and then it goes to normal one row.

P.S. Dont mind that big big pictures... it's gonna be smaller sizes...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are serving scaled images thus your website speed is very slow
Dont scale image using `HTML` or `CSS`. Try to create a `php` function for resize them.
You have to specify cache validator.

The following resources have identical contents, but are served from different URLs. Serve these resources from a consistent URL to save 9 request(s) and 1.7KiB.

- https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i7!2i69!3i44!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i373056598!3m14!2sen-US!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e47!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!12m4!1e26!2m2!1sstyles!2zcy50OjZ8cy5lOmd8cC52Om9mZixzLnQ6NXxwLnY6b2ZmLHMudDozfHAudjpvZmYscy50OjF8cC52Om9mZixzLnQ6MnxwLnY6b2ZmLHMudDoxfHAudjpvZmYscy5lOmx8cC52Om9mZg!4e0&token=48356

  - https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i7!2i69!3i43!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i373056598!3m14!2sen-US!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e47!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!12m4!1e26!2m2!1sstyles!2zcy50OjZ8cy5lOmd8cC52Om9mZixzLnQ6NXxwLnY6b2ZmLHMudDozfHAudjpvZmYscy50OjF8cC52Om9mZixzLnQ6MnxwLnY6b2ZmLHMudDoxfHAudjpvZmYscy5lOmx8cC52Om9mZg!4e0&token=78498

Comment: what do u mean serve it from consistent url?

Comment: thank you and how ould I compress it? just by making it smaller?